# gcurl: command not found in Google Cloud Shell

Tags: google-cloud-platform

In Google Cloud Shell,  I would like to see a list of enabled service,
When I put the following command

gcurl "https://serviceusage.googleapis.com/v1/proj
ects/myProjectId/services?filter=state:ENABLED"

Then I got this error.

```
-bash: gcurl: command not found
```

How to install gcurl?

Answer (score 7):

`gcurl` is an alias for regular curl plus some headers:

```bash
alias gcurl='curl -H "Authorization: Bearer $(gcloud auth print-access-token)" -H "Content-Type: application/json"'
```

Please see Google's [dev environment service usage guide](https://cloud.google.com/service-usage/docs/getting-started) for more details.